# Configuring Spring Web Sockets

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I followed the following example to get up and running a Spring project that uses Web sockets.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/
Now I'm trying to customize the project to my specific needs and facing a few issues.
For one I tried to rename the `static` folder inside `resources` to some other name, say `webapp`.
I added the following configuration file to support the change.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

However now when I run the application, on http://localhost:8080
I go into a whitelabel error page,

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 23 14:54:08 PDT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Any help with the configuration, will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you have followed the extending the right configureadapter . it should be AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer, not WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Comment: @kuhajeyan I've extended the AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer to configure the message broker. I'm extending the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to determine the serving of static assets.